# Meaning of N parameter in Chan Model LTspice

Tags: transformer, audio, ltspice

I'm trying to model an audio transformer for core saturation simulation but I don't understand what N parameter represents in the Chan model. It should be the number of turns of the windings but if I set it in the model I don't have what I expect from simulation. I see what I expect only if N is equal to one.
Could anyone explain me what N parameter exactly represent?

In the picture below you can see my transformer model.

[image]

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

`N` is part of the Chan core parameters (along with `Br, Bs, Hc, A, Lm, Lg`) and it means the number of turns. In this configuration (the one you're showing) it's part of the magnetizing inductance. This is used as a one turn inductor with all the parameters of the Chan core, so that the combination of VCVSs/CCCSs that make up the windings can use the full number of turns.

In case my words are fuzzy, think of it like this: you can have a one turn magnetizing inductance and then model the windings, each with its own number of turns, or you can have a magnetizing inductance with a certain number of turns and then model the windings with percentages of those number of turns.

E.g.: for `Np=100, Ns=25` you can have:

1. `Nmag=1, Np=100, Ns=25`
2. `Nmag=100, Np=1, Ns=0.25`

You can also use `Nmag=10, Np=10, Ns=2.5`, or any other numbers that satisfy the ratio, but it would just look confusing. For the same reason, `Nmag=1` is used, to let both `Np` and `Ns` be meaningful to what they represent.

Comment: Nice and clear.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for the explanation